# A windows client unable to connect

Tags: vpn, asuswrt

One of our windows client is unable to connent to our ipsec vpn server which is on an asus router. It seems it happend without any change on the client or on the router side. The windows laptop throws the following [error](https://imgur.com/a/VybGh8g).

and here is the log ont router side: https://pastebin.com/UYi7CXMR

What sould I do to figure out the issue and solve it.

Comment: `It seems it happend without any change on the client or on the router side.` - this is not how computers work ... if something stops working, it's because something has changed

Comment: Yes I know that.. thats why I frased my sentence "it seems". :)
I tried the basic stuff, like redo the vpn setup on the clinent laptop,  delete then create the user on the router side. 
But now I am stuck and don't know wheres should I contines my investigation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I did that thank you for the input

Answer (score 0):

After a while we found a solution.
Changed a the VPN settings on the windows computer:
Type of connection from "L2TP/IPsec" to "automatic"

That is weird cause on other instance we set it to "L2TP/IPsec" and worked.
Thanks anyway.